# Size of pid_t, uid_t, gid_t on Linux

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, 32-bit, sizeof

On Linux systems (either 32- or 64-bit), what is the size of `pid_t`, `uid_t`, and `gid_t`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    printf("pid_t: %zu\n", sizeof(pid_t));
    printf("uid_t: %zu\n", sizeof(uid_t));
    printf("gid_t: %zu\n", sizeof(gid_t));
}
```

**EDIT:** Per popular request (and because, realistically, 99% of the people coming to this question are going to be running x86 or x86_64)...

On an i686 and x86_64 (so, 32-bit and 64-bit) processor running Linux >= 3.0.0, the answer is:

```
pid_t: 4
uid_t: 4
gid_t: 4
```

Comment: The answers are portable to all Linux targets as far as I know. They're all 4.

Comment: Actually, the code was not portable, because the format specifier was `%d` but `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned and not necessarily the size of an `int`.  The correct portable format specifier is `%zu`.  I have fixed it.

Comment: Would be nice to also include the results for at least one example architecture.

Comment: does 4 mean 4 bytes?

Comment: @Zap yes (long pedantic answer: it means four `char`s, and a single `char` is the closest thing C has to a byte... of course a "byte" is *usually* an octet (8 bits), but it originally meant *smallest individually addressable unit of memory* - on some hardware that's a different size than 8 bits, but C requires a `char`/byte to be *at least* 8 bits, and anything else is rather rare unless you're writing bare metal code for DSPs).

Answer (score 28):

On intel architectures, sizes are defined in `/usr/include/bits/typesizes.h`:

```
#define __UID_T_TYPE            __U32_TYPE
#define __GID_T_TYPE            __U32_TYPE
#define __PID_T_TYPE            __S32_TYPE
```

In other words, `uid_t` and `gid_t` are unsigned 32-bit integers and `pid_t` is a signed 32-bit integer.  This applies for both 32- and 64-bits.

I am not sure what they are on other architectures offhand as I don't have any available at the moment, but the definitive way is to compile a program which prints the output of `sizeof(uid_t)`, etc.

Comment: `I am not sure what they are on other architectures offhand` => on Linux, they are the same regardless of architecture. However, on other operating systems, it can differ: on 64-bit AIX, `pid_t` is a signed 64-bit integer, but the kernel never assigns PIDs outside of the 32-bit range, for compatibility with 32-bit processes, which use a 32-bit `pid_t`. Also, on some 32-bit platforms (e.g. Solaris), while `pid_t` is still signed 32-bit, it is `long` rather than `int`-which are physically identical, but C treats them as different types, which can cause some compilation warnings around casts/etc

Answer (score 18):

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/toc.htm) defines `pid_t` as a "signed integer type" and `uid_t` and `gid_t` merely as "integer types" (so portable code shouldn't assume any particular type for them).

Comment: My manpage for `types.h`, which claims to be POSIX, says `uid_t` and `gid_t` are integer types (no mention of signed or unsigned), and `pid_t` is a signed integer type.

Comment: @Chris I was wrong about "pid_t", so I corrected my posting. The standard doesn't say anything about the signedness of "uid_t" or "gid_t", however.

Comment: Note that the standard also provides the `id_t` type, which “can be used to contain at least a `pid_t`, `uid_t`, or `gid_t`”.

Comment: The pid_t data type is a signed integer type which is capable of representing a process ID. In the GNU C Library, this is an int. (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Identification.html)