# What is the correct printf specifier for printing pid_t

Tags: c, io, printf, pid

I'm currently using a explicit cast to long and using `%ld` for printing `pid_t`, is there a specifier such as `%z` for `size_t` for `pid_t`?

If not what the best way of printing `pid_t`?

Comment: I am getting.                    %d
hello.c:9:42: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type
      'pid_t' (aka 'int') [-Wformat] when I try ld

Comment: @KorayTugay Note the words above: "I'm currently using a explicit cast to long".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's no such specifier. I think what you're doing (casting the `pid_t` to `long` and printing it with `"%ld"`) is fine; you could use an even wider int type, but there's no implementation where `pid_t` is bigger than `long` and probably never will be.

Comment: Nice. If you would like to customize `printf` with your own spec for `pid_t`, check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260170/is-this-possible-to-customize-printf

Comment: Is the total number of processes related to how bits the os is? e.g can a  os have more sizeof(int)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922761/size-of-pid-t-uid-t-gid-t-on-linux ... pid_t is usually 32 bits, regardless of the OS bit size. A system *could* have larger ones, but I wouldn't expect it. In any case, long will be plenty for safety.

Comment: Hmmm, if [pid_t is usually 32 bits, regardless of the OS bit size.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533606/what-is-the-correct-printf-specifier-for-printing-pid-t/44504623#comment30706088_20533635) is true then on implementations where `long` is 64-bit, printing with a `"%ld"` will certainly cause issues.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Please read the question: "***I'm currently using a explicit cast to long*** and using %ld" -- that's what I said "is fine". Of course there is a problem with using %ld without guaranteeing that a long is being passed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you could also write a macro similar to `PRIi32`: `#define PRIpid "i"`.

Answer (score 18):

With integer types lacking a matching format specifier as in the case of `pid_t`, yet with known sign-ness<sup>1</sup>, cast to widest matching signed type and print.

```
pid_t pid = foo();

// Since C99
#include <stdint.h>
printf("pid = %jd\n", (intmax_t) pid);
```

Or

```
// Since C99
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
printf("pid = %" PRIdMAX "\n", (intmax_t) pid);
```

Or

```
// pre-C99
pid_t pid = foo();
printf("pid = %ld\n", (long) pid);
```

If sign-ness is not known for other system type, cast to the widest unsigned type or [alternate opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533606/what-is-the-correct-printf-specifier-for-printing-pid-t/44504623?noredirect=1#comment105105662_44504623)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The `pid_t` data type is a [signed integer](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Identification.html)  type which is capable of representing a process ID.

Comment: "If sign-ness is not known, cast to the widest unsigned type" -- I would not advise this. Casting to `uintmax_t` and printing with `%ju` will print all negative values incorrectly, whereas casting to `intmax_t` and printing with `%jd` will only print values > `INTMAX_MAX` incorrectly. (Then again, situations in which one really doesn't know whether a type includes negative values are quite rare.)

Comment: @JimBalter Fair point.  With sign-ness unknown there is the trade-off of wrongly printing negative value as large values or large values as negative.  I'd expect when sign-ness unknown, it is usually  more natural to  use `intmax_t` as small values are more common, yet conversion _signed integer_ to `uintmax_t` is more narrowly defined which does not lose info (hence my preference) than _unsigned integer_ to `intmax_t` can. [Choose your poison](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pick%2Fchoose%20your%20poison) .