# Why my pipe doesn't work in my multithreads client-server program?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pipe

I implemented a client-server program with threads. The server programm must read from two clients 100 messages with socket and after it has to write this data on a pipe to make a fourth program read it. I successfully read the data from the socket but i'm not able to write on the pipe; my "write" system call doesn't work: what can I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h> 

#define DIM 100

void logFile(char *msgStatus) {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("logFileEs1.log", "a+");
    time_t currentTime;
    char* timeString;
    currentTime = time(NULL);
    timeString = ctime(&currentTime);
    fprintf(f, "%sPID %d. %s: %s\n",timeString, getpid(), msgStatus, strerror(errno));
    fclose(f);
} //function for the creation of the log file
int j=0;

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

struct message {  //dichiarazione struct
 time_t timestamp;  
 char g;  //process identifier
 int x;
};

struct message m1[DIM];
struct message m2;

void *func_thread(void *p)
{
    int nfd;
    nfd= *(int*) p;
    int n;  //for reading

    while(read(nfd,&m2,sizeof(m2))!=0) { //reading

        printf("Here is the message: %d from process %d at time %ld     %d\n",m2.x, m2.g, m2.timestamp, j);
        fflush(stdout);
        m1[j]=m2;
        j++;
    }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *f;
 f = fopen("logFileEs2.log", "w");
 fclose(f);

    pthread_t id[2];

    void *dummy;
    int iret1, i=0, d, t;
    int pipeState, execState1, data;
    pid_t child;

    int sockfd,newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    portno=6076;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;  //adress of the server and the client

    /*if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }*/

    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  //new socket creation
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_UNIX;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");

    listen(sockfd,5);
    printf("Listening\n");

    while(i<2) {
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0) 
            error("ERROR on accept");


        iret1 = pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, func_thread, &newsockfd);
        if (iret1) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            return -1;
        }

        i++;

    }
    pthread_join(id[0], &dummy);
    pthread_join(id[1], &dummy);

    char readPipe[5]; //string for reading pipe
    char writePipe[5]; //string for writing pipe
    int fd[2]; //file descriptor pipe1


    pipeState = pipe (fd);  //creation first pipe
    if (pipeState < 0) {
        perror("Pipe error");
        return -1;
    }


    close(fd[0]);
    for (t=0; t<DIM; t++) {
        printf("%d\n", m1[t].x); 
    }



    data = write(fd[1], &m1, sizeof(m1));


        if (data < 0) { //if written value is not valid
            perror("Write error\n");
            return -1;
        }
    printf("Data written on pipe\n");
    close(fd[1]);
    printf("Data written on pipe\n");
    fflush(stdout);


    //fd conversion from integer to string
    sprintf(readPipe, "%d", fd[0]);
    sprintf(writePipe, "%d", fd[1]);

    char *function[] = {"M", readPipe, writePipe, NULL};

    child=fork();

    /*if (child1 != 0) {
        logFile("Creation of the child1: ");
    }*/

    if (child < 0) {
        perror  ("Fork error in child1");
        return -1;
    }

    else if (child == 0) {

        execState1=execve("M", function,NULL);
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    else { wait(NULL);
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


    return 0; 
}
```

Thanks for attention :)

Comment: What exactly does "my 'write' system call doesn't work" mean?  Does the call fail with an error? (If so, which?)  Does it succeed, but produce a different result than you expect? (If so, then what did you expect, and what did you actually get?)

Comment: @JohnBollinger it doesn't to anything. It doesn't give an error and my program doesn't continue its execution because doesn't arrive to the printf("Data written on pipe").

Comment: Concerning using `"%d"` with `getpid()`,  [What is the correct printf specifier for printing pid_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533606/what-is-the-correct-printf-specifier-for-printing-pid-t) to avoid UB.

Comment: regarding: `while( read( nfd, &m2, sizeof(m2) ) != 0 ) `  the function: `read()` can return values less than 0 (as when an error occurs)  The code should be checking for <0 and handling the error

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  I.E. do not write lines like: `else { wait(NULL);` nor `int iret1, i=0, d, t;`  2) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Names like `d` and `t` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: OT: regarding: `listen(sockfd,5);`  the call to `listen()` can fail, so the code should be checking for that, similar to the way is checks for an error on `bind()`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note, other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: regarding the definition of : `clilen` this should not be declared an `int`  rather it should be declared as: `socklen_t` which is an unsigned value

Comment: regarding: `portno` this should be a `uint16_t`, not a `int`

Comment: regarding: `execState1=execve("M", function,NULL);
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);`  1) all of the `exec*()` functions do not ever return unless an error occurred.  So, if it ever returns, that is an error.  So they should always be followed by: `perror( "your error message" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdout);`  this 'should' never be necessary,  Rather, always end the format string in a call to `printf()` with a '\n'

Comment: regarding: `return -1;`  When an error occurs, that cannot be corrected, use: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` rather than a call to `return`

Comment: regarding: `m1[j]=m2;`  this will not copy the struct contents.  Suggest using `memcpy( &m1[j], &m2, sizeof( struct message ) );`

Comment: OT: do you have an executable called `M`?  Suggest posting that function so we can help you determine if it is ready to actually do anything.

Comment: in the function: `main()`, the final statement: `return 0;` will never be executed because all possible execution paths (the results of the call to `fork()` are already covered

Comment: the function: `logfile()` is never called!  why have a function that is never called?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least three [race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition) in your code, where data is used by one thread while it may be modified by another.

This code creates race conditions:

```
struct message m1[DIM];
struct message m2;

void *func_thread(void *p)
{
    int nfd;
    nfd= *(int*) p;
    int n;  //for reading

    while(read(nfd,&m2,sizeof(m2))!=0) { //reading

        printf("Here is the message: %d from process %d at time %ld     %d\n",m2.x, m2.g, m2.timestamp, j);
        fflush(stdout);
        m1[j]=m2;
        j++;
    }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

*Every* thread shares the same `m1` and `m2` data structures, overwriting each other's data when they read into `m2`.  They also make simultaneous updates to `j`, so its value can't be trusted in either thread.

Also, you have no idea how many bytes you've actually read.

This code creates another data race:

```
while(i<2) {
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR on accept");


    iret1 = pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, func_thread, &newsockfd);
    if (iret1) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        return -1;
    }

    i++;

}
```

Combine that with

```
void *func_thread(void *p)
{
    int nfd;
    nfd= *(int*) p;
```

and the child thread is accessing `newsockfd` from the main thread, but `newsockfd` may have a different value by the time the child thread accesses it.

A better way:

```
struct message m1[DIM];
int j = 0
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *func_thread(void *p)
{
    // each thread needs its own struct
    struct message m2;

    // pass the socket by **value**
    int nfd = ( intptr_t ) p;

    for ( ;; )
    {
        // don't put code that needs error checks inside conditions
        // because you can't handle errors, nor in this case partial
        // read results
        ssize_t bytes_read = read( nfd, &m2, sizeof( m2 ) );
        if ( bytes_read == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
        // really should put code here to handle a partial read()

        printf("Here is the message: %d from process %d at time %ld     %d\n",
            m2.x, m2.g, m2.timestamp, j);
        fflush(stdout);

        // another race condition if this isn't mutex'd
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

        // get a local copy of the current value of j so
        // the structure assignment can be moved outside
        // the mutex-locked critical section
        int my_j = j;
        j++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

        // stay within the bounds of the array
        if ( my_j >= DIM )
        {
            break;
        }
        m1[my_j]=m2;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Note that `newsockfd` is now passed by **value**, not address, so the `pthread_create()` call needs to be:

```
    iret1 = pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, func_thread, ( void * )( intptr_t ) newsockfd);
```

That's a bit of a hack that relies upon your platform being able to pass an `int` value such as `newsockfd` as a `void *`, but whatever system you're currently using almost certainly can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about this section of your code (whitespace modified):

> ```
>     int fd[2]; //file descriptor pipe1
>
>     pipeState = pipe(fd);  //creation first pipe
>     if (pipeState < 0) {
>         perror("Pipe error");
>         return -1;
>     }
>
>     close(fd[0]);
>     for (t=0; t<DIM; t++) {
>         printf("%d\n", m1[t].x); 
>     }
>
>     data = write(fd[1], &m1, sizeof(m1));
>
>     if (data < 0) { //if written value is not valid
>         perror("Write error\n");
>         return -1;
>     }
>
>     printf("Data written on pipe\n");
>     close(fd[1]);
>     printf("Data written on pipe\n");
>     fflush(stdout);
> ```

I'm having trouble determining what behavior is expected.  I observe that the read end of the pipe is closed immediately after the pipe is successfully created, which makes the pipe useless.  This ought not to cause subsequent `write()`s to the write end to block indefinitely, but only because they should instead fail with `EPIPE`.

If you want to communicate with another process over the pipe, then you should `fork()` that other process after creating the pipe but before closing either end.  The parent and child then each close their copy of the end they do not intend to use.