# fork() not waiting for child

Tags: c, fork, wait

I thought wait paused the main execution untill child process finished.

---

The following is what I was expecting to see in the console.

I am the parent with id 12833 <- parent

I'm calling first with id 0 <- child

I'm calling first with id 12833 <- parent after wait()

---

Instead I see this...
#console output

I am the parent with id 12833

I'm calling first with id 12833

I'm calling first with id 0

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int id = fork();

    if(id!=0){
        //
        printf("I am the parent with id %d\n",id);
        wait(); //my code has no respect for wait()
    }

    printf("I'm calling first with id %d\n",id);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no such function `pid_t wait(void)`. Look at man wait: `pid_t wait(int *wstatus)`.

Comment: And you have to include `<sys/wait.h>` to get it.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but `fork()` returns `pid_t`, not `int`.  You'll then have to adjust the `printf` accordingly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533606/what-is-the-correct-printf-specifier-for-printing-pid-t.

Comment: @NateEldredge it was a combination of <sys/wait.h> and passing the right parameters to the wait function as S.M showed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My output is

```
I'm calling first with id 0
I am the parent with id 29807
I'm calling first with id 29807
```

You should not rely on buffered outputs. Check returned values of `wait.`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int id = fork();

    if(id!=0){
        printf("I am the parent with id %d\n", id);
        int wstatus = 0;
        if (wait(&wstatus) != -1) //my code has no respect for wait()
            printf("I am the parent with id %d and my child exited\n", id);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I'm child\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is again is not what you would expect due to buffered outputs.

```
I'm child
I am the parent with id 18057
I am the parent with id 18057 and my child exited
```

If you flush the output buffers, you get the desired output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int id = fork();

    if(id!=0){
        printf("I am the parent with id %d\n", id);
        fflush(stdout);
        int wstatus = 0;
        if (wait(&wstatus) != -1) //my code has no respect for wait()
        {
            printf("I am the parent with id %d and my child exited\n", id);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I'm child\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
I am the parent with id 21487
I'm child
I am the parent with id 21487 and my child exited
```

Comment: Still, if stdout is line buffered, as would normally be the case when it is a terminal, the flush shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘wait::wait(int*)’
         int x = wait(&wstatus);

my compiler is not liking addresses as a parameter in wait()

Comment: Probably missing `#include <sys/wait.h>`.

Comment: Yea I saw a comment from Nate Eldredge about it, trying again