# FIFO pipe content contains wrong chars after read

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fifo

I created a program which looking for a maximum in an integer array parallel on 10 thread and has a parent and a child process. Child calculate the maximum of interval's (array has 1000 elements) maximum and write to the named pipe, parent just reads the max number from the FIFO and print it. When I wanna read content from FIFO, the read content contains some wrong characters but the input string is ok.
How can I avoid this problem?

[image]

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define max 1000

#define Th_max 10

int numbers[max];

int max_num[Th_max] = { 0 };
int thread_no = 0;

void *maximum(void* arg)
  ....
}

int main()
{
    int maxs = 0;
    int i;
    char buf[32];
    int fd, ret;
    int pipefd[2];  
     pid_t cpid;
    pthread_t threads[Th_max];

    srand(time(0));
    for( i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
        numbers[i] = rand();
   }
    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
       perror("fork");
       exit(-1);
    }
    if (cpid == 0) {
        printf("PID: %d : Child process \n",getpid());

        for (i = 0; i < Th_max; i++)
            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,
                        maximum, (void*)NULL);



        for (i = 0; i < Th_max; i++)
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);


        for (i = 0; i < Th_max; i++) {
            if (max_num[i] > maxs)
                maxs = max_num[i];
        }   
        fd=open("Pipe",O_RDWR);
        
        sprintf(buf, "%d", maxs);
        printf("PID: %d :Write this to FIFO: %s:%ld\n",getpid(),buf,strlen(buf));
        write(fd,buf,strlen(buf)); 

        exit(0);
        
        
     } else {
           printf("PID: %d : Parent process\n",getpid());

           ret=mkfifo("Pipe",00666);    
           if (ret == -1) {
               perror("mkfifo()");
               exit(-1);
            }

           fd=open("Pipe",O_RDWR);
           if (fd == -1) {
               perror("open() error!");
               exit(-1);
            }


            wait(NULL);   
            ret=read(fd,buf,32); 
            printf("PID: %d :Read %d byte: %s\n",getpid(),ret,buf);

            close(fd);
            
            unlink("LA3WXZ");   
    }


    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: `content contains wrong characters`  Could you post an example?>

Comment: You read 10 characters and then printed more than 10 characters. How were you expecting the `printf` line to know how many characters to print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's code is attempting to print an array of characters as a *string*.  It is not the desired *string* as it lacks a *null character* after the 10th character..

Instead use a *precision* to limit printing a character array.

```
//printf("PID: %d :Read %d byte: %s\n",getpid(),ret,buf);
printf("PID: %d :Read %d byte: %.*s\n",getpid(),ret, ret, buf);
//                              ^^                   ^^^ precision
```

Or only read up to 1 less character and append a 0.

```
// ret=read(fd,buf,32); 
ret = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1); 
if (ret >= 0) {
  buf[ret] = '\0';
  ...
```

Or send the null character.

```
// write(fd,buf,strlen(buf));
write(fd,buf,strlen(buf) + 1);
```

Or ...

---

Note: `getpid()` does not certainly return an `int`.  [Cast to a wide type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504623/2410359) and print.

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long) getpid());
```