# customize printf with extra common parameters

Tags: c

I would like to create a customized print function, the usage the same as printf but add 2 more parameter for pid and tid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int gettid() {
    return syscall(__NR_gettid);
}

void print( const char *fmt,...) {
    va_list vlist;
    va_start(vlist, fmt);

    va_end(vlist);
    return;
}

int main() { 
    printf("%d %d hello\n",getpid(), gettid());
    //print("hello\n");
    return 0;
```

What's proper way to implement the print function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your function first print the pid and tid, then use `vprintf` to print what's left.

```
void print( const char *fmt,...) {
    va_list vlist;

    printf("%d %d ", getpid(), gettid());

    va_start(vlist, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, vlist);
    va_end(vlist);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78084213/2410359) good answer:

---

> What's proper way to implement the print function?

For general use, consider returning a useful value like `int printf()` does.

> The `printf` function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.
> C23dr § 7.23.6.3 2

Also review [What is the correct printf specifier for printing pid_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20533606/2410359)

```
int print(const char *fmt, ...) {
    int num_written1 = printf("%jd %jd ", 
        (intmax_t) getpid(), (intmax_t) gettid());
    if (num_written1 < 0) {
      return num_written1;
    }

    va_list vlist;
    va_start(vlist, fmt);
    int num_written2 = vprintf(fmt, vlist);
    va_end(vlist);

    if (num_written2 < 0) {
      return num_written2;
    }
    return num_written1 + num_written2;
}
```

Ref: [`gettid()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html)

Comment: Awesome, if we still want to simplify it, can we combine two print command into one maybe?

Comment: @lucky1928 Combine: possible yes yet with difficulties, simpler no.