# Why clone returns int, not pid_t?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, glibc

From [man 2 clone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    /* Prototype for the glibc wrapper function */
>
>    #define _GNU_SOURCE
>    #include <sched.h>
>
>
>    int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack,
>              int flags, void *arg, ...
>              /* pid_t *ptid, void *newtls, pid_t *ctid */ );
> ```
>
> RETURN VALUE
>          On success, the thread ID of the child process is returned in the
>          caller's thread of execution.  On failure, -1 is returned in the
>          caller's context, no child process will be created, and errno will be
>          set appropriately.

Since using `pid_t` as the return type

1. improve the readability
2. improve the maintainability
3. is also capable of returning `-1` when an error occurs

Why `clone` does not return `pid_t`, instead returns `int`?

Comment: The `ptid` parameter which is of type `pid_t` already contains the ID of the child thread.

Comment: @P.W Yes, but since it also returns the thread ID of the child process, why shouldn't it be `pid_t` instead of `int`?

Comment: The type of `pid_t` is implementation defined. It does not have to be signed. If it is unsigned it cannot return -1.

Comment: @P.W If `pid_t` is unsigned, `fork()` and `vfork()` will be broken because they both return `-1` on  failure and use `pid_t` as return type.

Comment: Does the return value of clone always match what is stored in ptid?

Comment: @P.W For that to work, `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID` must be or-ed into the `flag`. So no, it does not always match.

Comment: @P.W Linux requires a signed `pid_t`; [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931823/2410359)

Comment: Hmmm given "*nix" requirement of "The implementation shall support one or more programming environments in which the widths of blksize_t, pid_t, size_t, ssize_t, suseconds_t, and useconds_t are no greater than the width of type long.", I'd expect  `clone()` to return `pid_t` or `long`.  "Why clone does not return pid_t, instead returns int?" --> appears to be a not completely thought out design. I do not see an `int` advantage/rational.

Comment: @chux I agree with you on that. On the `Note` of the manpage of `clone`, it is shown that the underlying syscall `clone` returns `long`.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu Perhaps it is worth submitting to GNU/Linux a request for change?

Comment: @chux It is. But how to? I haven't done anything like that before.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu I do not know either.

Comment: @chux Maybe [FilingBug - glibc wiki](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FilingBugs)